Data normalization using normalizr
I need to normalize data from https://dummyjson.com API into the correct form for reduxjs consumption.
I got the data from https://dummyjson.com/posts?limit=5&skip=10
{   "posts": [     {       "id": 11,       "title": "It wasn't quite yet time to panic.",       "body": "It wast time to salvage the situation, but he continued to delude himself into believing there was.",       "tags": [         "mystery",         "american",         "history"       ],       "reactions": {         "likes": 453,         "dislikes": 8       },       "views": 984,       "userId": 43     },     {       "id": 12,       "title": "She was aware that things could go wrong.",       "body": "Shd no idea just how wrong everything would go that day.",       "tags": [         "love",         "english"       ],       "reactions": {         "likes": 362,         "dislikes": 45       },       "views": 480,       "userId": 82     }, ...   ] }

I'm trying to normalize them using a schema:
 const post = new schema.Entity('post'); export const postsSchema = {   posts: [post], };

I got the following:
{    "entities": {         "post": {             "1": {                 "id": 1,                 "title": "His mother had always taught him",                 "body": "Hidddnd.",                 "tags": [                     "history",                     "american",                     "crime"                 ],                 "reactions": {                     "likes": 192,                     "dislikes": 25                 },                 "views": 305,                 "userId": 121             },             "2": {                 "id": 2,                 "title": "He was an expert but not in a discipline",                 "body": "He wddddt.",                 "tags": [                     "french",                     "fiction",                     "english"                 ],                 "reactions": {                     "likes": 859,                     "dislikes": 32                 },                 "views": 4884,                 "userId": 91             },                        }     },     "result": {         "posts": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],         "total": 251     } }

But I need the following:
{    "total": 251    "entities": {         "post": {             "1": {                 "id": 1,                 "title": "His mother had always taught him",                 "body": "Hidddnd.",                 "tags": [                     "history",                     "american",                     "crime"                 ],                 "reactions": {                     "likes": 192,                     "dislikes": 25                 },                 "views": 305,                 "userId": 121             },             "2": {                 "id": 2,                 "title": "He was an expert but not in a discipline",                 "body": "He wddddt.",                 "tags": [                     "french",                     "fiction",                     "english"                 ],                 "reactions": {                     "likes": 859,                     "dislikes": 32                 },                 "views": 4884,                 "userId": 91             },                        }     },      "result": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] } 

Thanks for help guys !
